# Two boolean properties in one radio choice

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have two properties

```
public bool IsSelOne {get; set;}
public bool IsSelTwo {get; set;}
```

currently there are inside view represented trough checkbox.
How can without changing properties represent those choices trough radio button (`IsSelOne`, `IsSelTwo`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to use a RadioButton is to map it with an enum. 
Anyway, you can use this kind of trick which needs an additional property :

```
public bool IsSelOne {get; set;}
public bool IsSelTwo {get; set;}

public bool Selection { 
   get { 
       return IsSelOne ; 
   } 
   set {
       IsSelOne = value;  
       IsSelTwo = !value ; 
   } 
}
```

Then in your view :

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Selection, true) ; // Radio for IsSelOne true 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Selection, false) ; // Radio for  IsSelTwo true
```